# Pyrogram: how to run async method in FastAPI router

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, pyrogram

**How i can run pyrogram method in FastApi routes?**

I use [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) and i have some methods for working with Telegram.

```
class UserBot: 
     def __init__(self, username: str, debug: Optional[bool] = False) -> None:
        self.username = username
        self.app = Client(f"sessions/{username}")

# For example get chat history (https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat_history)
    async def get_chat_history(self, chat_id: str) -> "List of chat messages":
        try:
            messages = list()
            async with self.app as app:
                async for message in app.get_chat_history(chat_id):
                    print(message)
                    messages.append(message)

            logging.INFO()
            return messages

        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

To run the methods, I use the built-in run function in the pyrogram Client

```
    async def loop_methods(self, fn):
        try:
            self.app.run(fn)
            logging.INFO()
        except Exception as e:
            return e
```

Run method example:

```
ubot = UserBot(username="donqhomo", debug=False)
ubot.loop_methods(ubot.get_chat_history(chat_id="@CryptoVedma"))
```

---

I want to run my pyrogram method in fastapi router, how i can do this? I'm try this, but no messages were printed to the terminal:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test/")
async def test():
    ubot = UserBot(username="donqhomo", debug=False)

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    task1 = loop.create_task(ubot.get_chat_history(chat_id="@CryptoVedma"))
    await task1

    return task1
```

And how i can take output from pyrogram method in fastapi?

Comment: Instead of running the bot inside FastAPI, it's usually a better approach to run the bot in a separate process and then exchange messages through a database/queuesystem (sqlite, redis, or similar). But first; does this give you expected messages back if you run it _outside_ of the FastAPI context with the exact same arguments?

Answer (score 0):

try tris code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test/")
async def test():
    ubot = UserBot(username="donqhomo", debug=False)
    return await bot.get_chat_history(chat_id="@CryptoVedma")
```

Comment: In output: INFO:     ``` 
INFO:     127.0.0.1:41344 - "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK ``` But nothing in terminal and response in postman is : {}

Comment: looks like  bot.get_chat_history() return {} or None in your case

Comment: i add messages.append(message) in loop in get_chat_history method, but result is also {}